# ActiveMQ Artemis GUI Jolokia access in docker container

Tags: docker, activemq-artemis, hawtio, jolokia

I'm running ActiveMQ Artemis inside of docker containers for our three environments (DEV/QA/PROD).

The management console typically runs on port 8161 and so I included this in the `artemis create` statement when I created the broker.

```
--http-host 0.0.0.0 --http-port 8161
```

So this causes the following two changes that I can see:

1. bootstrap.xml gets the host/port:

   ```
   <web bind="http://0.0.0.0:8161" path="web">
      <app url="redhat-branding" war="redhat-branding.war"/>
      <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
      <app url="dispatch-hawtio-console" war="dispatch-hawtio-console.war"/>
      <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>
   ```
2. jolokia-access.xml gets the host/port:

   ```
   <allow-origin>*://0.0.0.0*</allow-origin>
   ```

I'm trying to access the ActiveMQ Artemis Hawtio management console from a remote computer, but the exposed docker ports are not `8161`.  They're the mapped ports `38161`, `48161`, & `58161`.

So when I login to the management console, I get:

```
Operation unknown failed due to: java.lang.Exception : Origin http://10.0.20.2:58161 is not allowed to call this agent
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined (http://10.0.20.2:58161/console/app/app.js:16:14127)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined (http://10.0.20.2:58161/console/app/app.js:16:14127)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that your jolokia-access.xml using this:

```
<allow-origin>*://0.0.0.0*</allow-origin>
```

However, you're attempting to access the console via `http://10.0.20.2:58161` which isn't allowed based on your `jolokia-access.xml`. Therefore you need to change the `jolokia-access.xml` to allow the IP:port you're actually going to use to connect.

You can read more about the jolokia-access.xml in the [Jolokia security documentation](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/security.html).

For clarity's sake, the meta-address `0.0.0.0` is basically the "no particular address" placeholder and in the context of binding a listener to a network interface it means the listener should bind/listen to *all* interfaces. However, in the context of `<allow-origin>` for Jolokia security it doesn't mean allow all origins. The `<allow-origin>` supports literal matches and wild-cards (as noted in the documentation linked above). Therefore, if `0.0.0.0` is specified it attempts to literally match `0.0.0.0`. There is no way to disable Jolokia security from the `create` command. If you were to pass something like `--http-host 10.0.20.*` to the `create` command then `10.0.20.*` would be used to bind the webserver in `bootstrap.xml` which would fail.

There is the option of using `--relax-jolokia` which will disable strict checking which may help your use-case.

Comment: Well the specific URL works after a restart, thanks.  I was under the impression that 0.0.0.0 was like a wildcard for IP addresses.  Is there a way to wildcard the IP / disable the security from the 'create' command?  I'm in a docker, so I don't want to have to make different versions for different machines.  Would --http-host 10.0.20.* --http-port *8161 work?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. If you believe this answer is correct please mark it as such to help users who may have this question in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Justin. Seems like there's no solution for me then, other than manually editing each docker deployed :( bootstrap and jolokia should have different parameter options. I doubt it's a rare case to run AMQ inside docker.  (At the point where AMQ is set up, there's no ports specified yet)

Comment: I updated my answer with an additional option and also opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2267 to support your use-case in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to make change on the jolokia-access.xml file to edit cors :

```
<allow-origin>*://*</allow-origin>
```

For more information about this you can refert to : https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/setup-activemq-artemis-on-ubuntu-18-04-76bb4975308b